# how do I install Kivy and kivymd in python 3.11.0

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

pip install "kivy[base]" kivy_examples:

```
Collecting kivy[base]
  Using cached Kivy-2.1.0.tar.gz (23.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-65.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
      Collecting cython!=0.27,!=0.27.2,<=0.29.28,>=0.24
        Using cached Cython-0.29.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
      Collecting kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev~=0.3.3
        Using cached kivy_deps.gstreamer_dev-0.3.3-cp311-cp311-win_amd64.whl (3.9 MB)
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5 (from versions: 0.5.1)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2_dev~=0.4.5
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

how to fix? if you could help me. I am receiving this error is it my python verson? or the kivy version what could it be.
I tried using these verions:

```
python -m pip install kivy --pre --no-deps --index-url  https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
python -m pip install "kivy[base]" --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
```

but they dont work properly, has a lot of bugs and malfunctions

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

There is no wheel for Kivy and Python 3.11 yet.
You have to build Kivy from source.  You can do that using the following commands.  I am doing it in a virtual environment to keep it separate from the main system.

```
python3.11 -m virtualenv Kivy_Py3.11
cd Kivy_Py3.11
source bin/activate
git clone https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git
cd kivy
python -m pip install -e ".[base]"
python -m pip install kivymd
pip freeze
```

Kivy will now be installed and the 'pip freeze' should show:  (version number will probably be different)

```
certifi==2022.12.7
charset-normalizer==2.1.1
docutils==0.19
idna==3.4
-e git+https://github.com/kivy/kivy.git@a7c66880270a93821e1f8ecd613409f008fd2ce8#egg=Kivy
Kivy-Garden==0.1.5
KivyMD==1.1.1
Pillow==9.3.0
Pygments==2.13.0
requests==2.28.1
urllib3==1.26.13
```

If you want to use the nightly build of Kivy that is more compatiable with Python 3.11 then you can just run these command.

```
python3.11 -m pip install kivy --pre --no-deps --index-url  https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
python3.11 -m pip install "kivy[base]" --pre --extra-index-url https://kivy.org/downloads/simple/
python3.11 -m pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it was rectified by downgrading to 3.10 and it works.